# Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin after meteor deployment

Tags: deployment, xmlhttprequest, meteor

I've managed to deploy my meteor project to my domain.

However, I kept getting this error.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://ddp--0417--51b282eb3404523b22000478.meteor.com/sockjs/684/twnudnik/xhr.
>   Origin http://meteor.youhock.sg is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin. admin:1

Is there any way to allow domain by Access-Control-Allow-Origin in meteorjs?

Thanks

Comment: How have you deployed it ?

Comment: i deployed it using meteorite 'mrt deploy meteor.youhock.sg' and set the dns to origin.meteor.com. I've remove the deployment for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

I know it does work with `A` record in your DNS as opposed to `CNAME`.

```
mrt deploy meteor.youhock.sg
```

Then set the DNS `A` record of `meteor.youhock.sg` in your domain's DNS management to `107.22.210.133`

Comment: hi, it has the same problem

Comment: it shouldn't have worked that fast, your DNS should take some time to adjust